# directive not working angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

The directive does not work from the controller. how to fix it?

```
baseapp.directive('loading', function () {
    alert('loading');
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div class="loading">loading</div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            scope.$watch('loading', function (val) {
                if (val) {
                    element.addClass('show');
                    alert('show');
                } else {
                    element.addClass('hide');
                    alert('hide');
                }
            });
        }
    }
});

baseapp.controller ('ListCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.loading = true;
    $http.get('/blog').success(function(data) {
        $scope.users = data;
        $scope.loading = false;
    });
});
```

When you load a directive called. from the controller $ scope.loading = true;
Nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I noticed is that your adding a class over and over `element.addClass('show');` resulting in if true and later false: `class='show hide show hide ...'` and so forth, one quick way to correct this is to remove one of the classes or you can toggle class:

```
 .directive('myDir', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div class="loading">loading</div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            scope.$watch('loading', function (val) {
                if (val===true) {
                    element.addClass('show');
                     element.removeClass('hide');
                } else {
                    element.toggleClass('hide');
                    element.removeClass('show');
                }
            });
        }
    }
    });
```

Other than that it seems to be working just fine on my end:

[**Online Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/7M4MTv4K6EDKzvNCqrBP?p=preview)

> **Note**: I recommend you not to use alerts for debugging use `console.log` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the official documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

You can read this:

> The restrict option is typically set to:
>   'A' - only matches attribute name
>   'E' - only matches element name
>   'C' - only matches class name

If you want to use it as a class like you do, then you have to specify :

```
require: 'C'
```